# Python iterate through df to create folders and copy files

Tags: python, directory

I have a data frame in Python.

```
import pandas as pd
inp = [{'image':'001.jpg', 'x':100, 'y':200,'w':100, 'h':200,  'brand':'test1'}, {'image':'001.jpg', 'x':100, 'y':200,'w':100, 'h':200, 'brand': 'test1'}, {'image':'001.jpg', 'x':100, 'y':200, 'w':100, 'h':200, 'brand': 'test2'}]
df = pd.DataFrame(inp)
print df
```

The data frame when printed looks like this:

```
    image   x   y   w   h   brand
0   001.jpg 100 200 100 200 test1
1   001.jpg 100 200 100 200 test1
2   001.jpg 100 200 100 200 test2

description
image: image name
x,y,w,h : crop coordinates
brand : destination folder
```

The images listed in the first column are stored in a particular directory.  I will call it as source directory.

```
src_path = '/var/www/html/projects/images/'
```

I have to iterate through the data frame, take each image from the first column, crop the subset based on the coordinates and save the cropped image in a folder created using the column 'folder'.

The following is the code so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import shutil
import cv2

#read the data frame
df = pd.read_csv('annotations.csv')

src_path = '/var/www/html/projects/images/'

# create a master folder to store all cropped images in separate sub-directories created basis the name in brand column

if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(src_path,'imageProcessDir')):
    os.mkdir(os.path.join(src_path,'imageProcessDir'))


dest_path = src_path+'imageProcessDir'

#create sub-directories for each brand
ub = df.brand.unique()    
for u in ub:
    os.mkdir(os.path.join(dest_path,u))

for index, rows in df.iterrows():
    #read each image
    image = cv2.imread(src_path+rows['image'])

    #crop image
    brand = image[rows['y']:rows['y']+rows['h'], rows['x']:rows['x']+rows['w']]

    #save the cropped image in specific directories as listed in folder column

    if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(dest_path, rows['brand'])):
        shutil.move(brand, os.mkdir(os.path.join(dest_path, rows['brand'])));
```

I am stuck at the last step, where I need to save the cropped image in the brand sub-directory.  The following would be the desired final directory structure:

```
dest_path
   |
imageProcessDir
   |__test1
        |_001_1.jpg #brand = image[rows....will go here
        |_001_2.jpg
   |__test2
        |_001_1.jpg
```

I can manage with renaming of the final output.

However, I am not able to match the directory name under the column df and the actual directory under imageProcessDir.

Comment: So the code runs and the files are not moving? Your logic looks OK. Can you try `if os.path.exists(os.path.join(dest_path, rows['brand'])):`, replacing the not? It may be stopping the `shutil` from executing

Comment: @VivekKalyanarangan Thank you. Yes...the code runs but the cropped images are not getting stored in individual sub-directories.  I tried removing the `not`  - I am getting a string vs numpy error.  `TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, numpy.ndarray found`

Comment: I'd like to make two recommendations. First, try using pathlib instead of os for working with your paths. Second, check out Pillow for cropping the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before trying to move the image, you will have to save it.

```
cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(dest_path, rows['brand']),brand)
```

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue.  Instead of using `shutil.move`, I used cv2.imwrite.  The last few lines of my code looks like this now:

```
counter = 0
for index, rows in df.iterrows():
    filename = basename(rows['imagename'])
    image = cv2.imread(src_path+rows['imagename'])
    brand = image[rows['y']:rows['y']+rows['h'], rows['x']:rows['x']+rows['w']]
    counter=counter+1
    fold = rows['brand']+"/"
    dest_fold = dest_path+fold  
    cv2.imwrite(dest_fold+"/"+filename+ "_" +str(counter)+".jpg", brand)
```

Comment: I just came to the same conclusion, you posted right before I did.

Comment: @MikePeder I have accepted your answer.  Thank you.